# How to convert an 18 digit numeric string to BigInteger?

Tags: java, biginteger

Could anyone help me in converting an 18 digit string numeric to BigInteger in java

ie;a string `"0x9999999999999999"` should appear as `0x9999999999999999` numeric value.

Answer (score 14):

You can specify the base in BigInteger constructor.

```
BigInteger bi = new BigInteger("9999999999999999", 16);
String s = bi.toString(16);
```

Answer (score 2):

If the String always starts with "0x" and is hexadecimal:

```
    String str = "0x9999999999999999";
    BigInteger number = new BigInteger(str.substring(2));
```

better, check if it starts with "0x"

```
  String str = "0x9999999999999999";
  BigInteger number;
  if (str.startsWith("0x")) {
      number = new BigInteger(str.substring(2), 16);
  } else {
      // Error handling: throw NumberFormatException or something similar
      // or try as decimal: number = new BigInteger(str);
  }
```

---

To output it as hexadecimal or convert to an hexadecimal representation:

```
    System.out.printf("0x%x%n", number);
    // or
    String hex = String.format("0x%x", number);
```

Comment: Watch out for negative values here!

Answer (score 1):

Do you expect the number to be in hex, as that is what 0x usually means?

To turn a plain string into a BigInteger

```
BigInteger bi = new BigInteger(string);
String text = bi.toString();
```

to turn a hexidecimal number as text into a BigInteger and back.

```
if(string.startsWith("0x")) {
    BigInteger bi = new BigInteger(string.sustring(2),16);
    String text = "0x" + bi.toString(16);
}
```

Comment: Not sure why there is a down vote given the second example produces the OP asked for output, @Carlos is the only other one which does. (He posted later)

Comment: This also does not consider negative values

Comment: @TheRealNeo can you give an example of a negative hexadecimal value you mean?

Comment: It is legal to prepend a sign to the number represented as a string. For instance, you can do new BigInteger("-a", 16) or new BigInteger("+a", 16) and by extension, the number could be represented as "-0xa" or "+0xa". It sounds like this problem could be solved more efficiently using regexps (the user could also use 0X as a prefix, ...).

Comment: @TheRealNeo it is more common to represent negative numbers like 0xFFFFFFFF for -1. You could add a sign but I don't think it is widely used.

Comment: Indeed, the 2-complement notation is common. My point was more for the sake of completeness, especially because this format is supported by BigInteger.

Answer (score 0):

```
BigInteger bigInt = new BigInteger("9999999999999999", 16);
```