# how to parse a big integer from a string?

Tags: java

I have a method like this:

```
Integer.parseInt(myInt)
```

not this integer becomes to long and I'm getting the following exception:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "4000123012"
```

what can I do to avoid this error and still keep alle the functions runnning?

I tried to use `BigInteger` but there is no `parse` method, or I did not found it.

Comment: Here is the complete answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4416618/how-to-convert-an-18-digit-numeric-string-to-biginteger

Comment: @MarounMaroun but BigInteger class has `BigInteger(String val)` constructor. I think your decision is too complex

Comment: @AlekseiBulgak You're right. I deleted my complex comment :D

Comment: it takes more time writing this on [SO] than finding the javadoc.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use it like this.

```
 BigInteger number = new BigInteger(myInt);
```

Comment: How can I convert "Alphanumeric" string into BigInteger?For Example: "123check"

Answer (score 8):

My solution :

```
String sLong = "4000123012";
long yourLong = Long.parseLong(sLong);
System.out.println("Long : "+yourLong);
```

OutPut :

```
Long : 4000123012
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Long.parse for integers too:

```
Long.parseLong(myInt)
```

which of course returns a `long`.

Answer (score 1):

Java Integer max value is 2147483647 ([table of limits](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.lang.Integer.MAX_VALUE)).

You can cast String to Long via [Long.parseLong(String s)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#parseLong%28java.lang.String%29) and get BigInteger by passing long to [BigInteger.valueOf(long l)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#valueOf%28long%29)

```
String s = "4000123012";
long l = Long.parseLong(s);
BigInteger bi = BigInteger(l);
```

EDIT:
You will always have to try and catch exception in case of parsing one type to another, and act in that case, for instance set some default value.

even better as [Alpesh Prajapati](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16730358/1603188) suggests, to pass String to constructor:

```
BigInteger number = new BigInteger(myInt);
```